# If the center of a circle is equidistant from the sides of an inscribed triangle, then the triangle is equilateral

Tags: geometry

The question is to prove that

> If the center of a circle is equidistant from the sides of an inscribed triangle, then the triangle is equilateral.

I can't find a simple solution.

Attempt: I believe that if a point is equidistant from the adjacent sides of a triangle, then it lies on the angle bisector but how would I use that to prove the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Add in line segments from the vertices of the triangle to the center of the circle.  The segments from the center to the sides of the triangle are radii; what is true about radii and tangent lines to a circle?  What can you say about all six smaller triangles into which the large triangle is subdivided?

Comment: Another hint: Call the triangle $ABC$ and the center of circle is $O$. and if $O$ is equidistance to, say, $AB$ and $AC$, then try to prove $AB=AC$ directly by projecting $O$ on both sides and using Pythagorean theorem. By proving the angular bisector as you attempted can be also probed by congruent triangles, but it takes more steps.

Comment: @boojum The radii are perpendicular to the tangent lines and the six smaller triangles are all congruent to each other. So if I were to show that the sides of the large triangle are all equal, then I proved that the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: @JetfiRex By projecting O do you mean reflecting O across AB and AC. If so how would I prove that AB = AC?

Comment: Projection DOES NOT MAKE REFLECTION, it is DRAW THE PERPENDICULAR LINE and TAKE THE INTERSECTION!!! Okay I will give a more detailed hint. We know that the projection of $O$ to $AB$, say $D$, is the midpoint of $AB$. And the projection of $O$ to $AC$, say $E$, is also the midpoint. Since equidistance, we have $OD=OE$, by Pythagorean theorem you can derive $AD=AE$, by midpoints you can derive $AB=AC$.